# Bounded Input Boundaed Output stability for heat equation. Proof or Counter example?

Tags: pde, fourier-analysis

I am interested in proving or obtaining a counterexample to the following conjecture.

Let $\Omega\in \mathbb{R}^d$ be a bounded open domain.  Let $u_d\in H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega) \times \mathbb{R}^+$. Suppose $u\in L^2((0,\infty); H^1(\Omega))$ is the weak solution of 
$$
\left\{
\begin{align*}
  u_t- \nabla \cdot \nabla u &= 0&\,  \mathrm{in}\,& (\Omega\times \mathbb{R}^+) \\
  u &= u_d&\, \mathrm{on}\,& (\partial\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+)\\
  u &= 0&\, \mathrm{at}&\, (\Omega \times \{0\})
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
Then there exists a constant $C$ dependent only on the domain $\Omega$ such that
$
\left\| u \right\|_{L^\infty((0,\infty); L^2(\Omega))} \le C \left\| u_d \right\|_{L^{\infty}((0,\infty); H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega))}.
$

I haven't been able to find many texts that treat the heat equation with time varying boundary conditions.  Thanks so much for any direction you can give me.  Thanks.

Addendum:  Following @WolfgangBangerth's advice we have the following.

Step One, convert non-homogeneous boundary conditions to a right hand side.

Let $u_{BC}\in H^1(\Omega) \times \mathbb{R}^+$ be the weak solution to the following elliptic problem

$$
  \left\{
\begin{align*}
-\nabla \cdot \nabla u_{BC} &= 0 & \mathrm{in}& (\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+)\\
 u_{BC} &=u_d &\mathrm{on} &(\partial\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+) 
\end{align*}
 \right.
$$

So $u_{BC}$ is the weak solution of an elliptic equation at each instant in time.

Now define $w = u-u_{BC}$.  Then we have that $w$ is the weak solution of the following homogeneous initial boundary value problem.
$$
\left\{
\begin{align*}
 w_t - \nabla \cdot \nabla w &= -(u_{BC})_t& \mathrm{in}& (\Omega\times \mathbb{R}^+)\\
 w &= 0& \mathrm{on}& (\partial\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+)\\ 
w &= -u_{BC}\big|_{t=0} &\mathrm{at} &(\Omega\times \{0\})
\end{align*}
\right.
$$

Step Two Provide bounds for each eigenfunction.

Let $\left\{(\lambda_i^2, V_i)\right\}_{i=1}^\infty\in (\mathbb{R}^+ \times H_0^1)$ be the  the eigenvalue and eigenfunction pairs ordered by increasing eigenvalue. Expand $w$ as $w = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \omega_i(t) V_i$ where $\omega_i(t)$ is the weight of the $i$'th eigenfunction at time $t$.

Then after testing the PDE with a test function $V_i$ we get

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \omega_i(t) + \lambda_i^2 \omega_i(t) = -(V_i, \frac{d}{dt} u_{BC})
$$

This ODE has solution

$$\omega_i(t) = \exp(-\lambda^2_i t) \omega_i(0) - \int_{\tau =0 }^t \exp(-\lambda_i^2(t-\tau))(V_i, \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\tau}u_{BC})\, \mathrm{d}\tau
$$

Then we integrate by parts on the integral term to get

$$
\begin{align*}\omega_i(t) =& \exp(-\lambda^2_i t) \omega_i(0) - (V_i, u_{BC}(t)) + (V_i, u_{BC}(0)) \exp(-\lambda^2_i t) \\
&+ \int_{\tau=0}^t \lambda_i^2 \exp(-\lambda_i^2 (t-\tau)) ( V_i, u_{BC}(\tau))\, \mathrm{d}\tau
\end{align*}
$$

Now, the sum of the first and third term vanishes because of the intial conditions for $u$ in the original problem.

So we are left with
$$
\begin{align*}\omega_i(t) =&  - (V_i, u_{BC}(t)) + \int_{\tau=0}^t \lambda_i^2 \exp(-\lambda_i^2 (t-\tau)) ( V_i, u_{BC}(\tau))\, \mathrm{d}\tau
\end{align*}
$$

Now expanding $u$ as $u = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathcal{u}_{i}(t) V_i$ and using the previous equation we get

$$\mathcal{u}_i(t) = \int_{\tau=0}^t \lambda_i^2 \exp(-\lambda_i^2 (t-\tau)) ( V_i, u_{BC}(\tau))\, \mathrm{d}\tau$$

Step Three Estimate.

Now
$$
\begin{align*}
\|u\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^+, L^2(\Omega)}^2\\
&= \sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}^+} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left(\mathcal{u}_i(t)\right)^2\\
&= \sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}^
+} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 
\left(\int_{\tau=0}^t \lambda_i^2\exp(-\lambda_i^2 (t-\tau)) (V_i,u_{BC}(\tau))\, \mathrm{d} \tau \right)^2\\
\end{align*}
$$

This is where I am stuck.  I have attempted estimates like the following but I run into problems because of the countably infinite quantity of eigenpairs.

$$
\begin{align*}
& \sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 
\left(\int_{\tau=0}^t \lambda_i^2\exp(-\lambda_i^2 (t-\tau)) (V_i,u_{BC}(\tau))\, \mathrm{d} \tau \right)^2\\
&\le \sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left(\sup_{\tau\in (0,t)} (V_i, u_{BC}(\tau)) \right)^2 \left(\int_{\tau=0}^t \lambda_i^2 \exp(-\lambda_i^2 \tau)\, \mathrm{d}\tau \right)^2\\
&\le \sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left(\sup_{\tau\in(0,t)}(V_i, u_{BC}(\tau) ) \right)^2
\end{align*}
$$

Any further estimation I perform I lose the boundedness.  I am guessing I just need a different inequality I am not thinking of.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Another Addendum:

I don't think it is legal to expand $u$ as $u= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathcal{u}_i V_i$ as all the $V_i$'s are zero on the boundary condition.  So a new strategy would be to bound $w$ and use Lax-Milgram and to $u_{BC}$ and then use the triangle inequality to bound $u$.

Comment: Isn't this straightforward application of maximum principle ? Time varying boundary condition is not an issue since for applying max. principle to heat equation, time domain is also part of the boundary, i.e. the boundary is $\Omega\times [0,T]$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Math.SE.

Comment: @PiyushGrover I don't think the maximum principle applies as I stated the problem.  The problem is that $ H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega) \not\subseteq L^{\infty}(\partial\Omega)$ at least that inclusion is not implied by the Sobolev Embedding theorem.  My intuition isn't as strong as it could be when dealing with fractional spaces.    Please correct me if I am wrong.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You immediately get $L^\infty$ stability by using the eigenfunction decomposition of the solution. The coefficient of each mode is strictly decreasing exponentially if you don't have a right hand side (or boundary) values, and consequently the $L_2$ norm of the solution decays. In your case, you need to write down the differential equation for each mode and prove stability for it; the stability for the entire solution the follows immediately by summation.

Comment: I have attempted your program and have run into a problem.  I am sending you an email with my approach.  Feel free to ignore it if you lack the time to look at it.  Thanks,

Comment: Post it as an addendum to your question above -- this way others get to learn from your obstruction, and can help out with it.